# Getting error while provide mySql Connection in spring boot application

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

> I use sql work bench as sql editor . when I provide database
> connection in my application I am get error . I get error when define
> driver class name in yml file  . I already added required dependency
> in my gradlle.kt file. But I do not know why I am get this issue. here
> is my db connection details
> application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital-management
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 12345678
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  banner:
    location: classpath:banner.txt




app:
  jwt:
    secret: ArbitrarySecretKey

    expiration-in-ms: 864000000
    token:
      prefix: Bearer
    header:
      string: Authorization
```

> gradle.kt

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.5.31"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.5.31"
}

group = "com.nillmani"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper
    implementation("org.modelmapper:modelmapper:2.3.6")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt
    implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

> I get error exact at this point

```
driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

> I get error for the name defination(com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver)
> It works fine for me While I run this application in windows system
> using sql yog. But getting issue in Mac os , in mac os I use sql work
> bench as editor. what is the reason for this issue

Answer (score 0):

> This type of error raises for versioning issue . Here I use MYSQL5 , I
> upgrade MYSQL5 to 8 . All the errors in driver class name vanished.
> This trick works for me .Here No issue in my db connection
> Before my depedency

```
runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
```

> after upgrade to

```
runtimeOnly("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. this package has a new name
2. specify version

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.1.0")
    // ... other ...
}
```